# Why does my AJAX request print out the pages entire HTML code?

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to make an AJAX request, send the data to a PHP file, check if the username and password are correct, return an answer, and then run the login.php file which determines runs the session.

Right now, my AJAX request does nothing except print out my entire HTML code for the login page.

If someone knows why, please let me know... 
(I apologize in advance for posting all of my login.js and checkLogin.php, I fear that the question may be unanswerable without the context for both)

This is login.js

```
$(function() { //Once the document has fully loaded 

    $("#login_form").submit(function(event) {

        //INITIALIZING VARIABLES
        var userName = $("#userName").val();
        var passWord = $("#passWord").val();
        var error = 0;

        event.preventDefault(); //Prevent normal submit action
        $("#userError, #passError").text(""); //Clear the text each time the user clicks submit

        if (userName == "") { //Checking if the username is blank
            $("#userError").text("Please enter your username");
            error = 1;
        }

        if (passWord == "") { //Checking if the password is blank
            $("#passError").text("Please enter your password");
            error = 1;
        }

        //BEGIN Ajax Request
        var $form = $(this),
            term = $form.find("userName, passWord"),
            url = 'checkLogin.php';

        var posting = $.post(url, {username: userName, password: passWord});

        posting.done(function(data) {
            $("#userError").text(posting.responseText);
        });
        //END Ajax Request

        if (error == 0) {
            $("passError").text("Success");
        }
    }); //END submit button click   

    $("#login_form").submit();

});
```

This is checkLogin.php

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB info private); //Database Connection

    if (!$link) { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { //Keeps the text inside the this.responseText
        //Preparing and Binding SQL statement
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT username, password FROM login WHERE username =? and password =?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password);

        //PRINTS UNIDENTIFIED INDEX
        $username = $_POST['username']; //Retrieving the username 
        $password = $_POST['password']; //Retrieving the password
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); //Execute the parameterized prepared statement

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
?>
```

Form tag from client_login.php

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" name="login_form" id="login_form">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi there. First of all, no need to apologize for posting all your code, the more you post, the more people will be able to help! Also at first glance of your code, you're not returning anything from "checkLogin.php". You should add a return in the "if" statement where you check if it is a POST request, that returns the data you are looking for in the "posting.done(...)" function in "login.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything on checkLogin.php. You should try:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row) {
    echo "User found!";
    exit();
}
```

I would recommend you, returning a text in json format. This way you can return more complex reponses to use in your js script. For example, in your checkLogin.php:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row) {
    echo json_encode([
        'code' => '1', // code that represent successful
        'message' => 'User found!'
    ]);
    exit();
}
```

And in your login.js:

```
posting.done(function(data) {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    if(response.code == '1') {
        $("#userError").text(response.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues here

1. `url = checkLogin.php;`  should be `url = 'checkLogin.php';`

   Right now url will be `undefined` and ajax url will post everything to `yoursite.com/undefined` and obiviosly the server will return 404 with default 404 page. Thats why you see html in your response.
2. Your`checkLogin.php` should return some data to client. Use `echo()` for that.

Comment: Thank you, that was an oversight, I've fixed it